# DataFrame column contains characters that are not numbers - how to convert to integer?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, replace, integer

I have the following Problem: I have  a dataframe that looks like this:

A   B

0  1  [5]

1  3  [1]

2  3  [118]

3  5  [34]

Now, I Need column B to only contain numbers, otherwise I can't work with the data. I already tried to use the replace-function and simply replace "[]" with "", but that didn't work out.

Is there any other way? Maybe I can convert the whole column to only keep the numbers as integers? That would be even better than just dropping the parenthesis.

I'm grateful for any help, I've been stuck with this for 2h now.

Comment: Your input is ambiguous. Please provide your dataframe as python object (use `df.to_dict('list')` to generate a dictionary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `B` column contains a string, use:

```
df['B'] = df['B'].str[1:-1].astype(int)
```

If your `B` column contains a list of one element, use:

```
df['B'] = df['B'].str[0]
```

**Update**

```
df['B'] = df['B'].str.extract(r'\[(.*)\]', expand=False).astype(int)
```

Comment: thanks very much, unfortunately this doesn't work: I just checked and my column contains objects, not strings... so I tried to make your second suggestion work but when I apply this, I only get the parenthesis back, not the number inside of it:
B
[
[
[

Comment: @Freyana. I updated my answer. I think you have whitespace before `[ ]`. In my updated solution, we are going to extract values between `[ ]`

Comment: @Freyana why don't you provide what I requested as comment to your question? This would save everyone's time ;)

Comment: now I get this error:
cannot convert float NaN to integer

Comment: Just remove `.astype(int)`. Does it work?